# send message to all clients

Tags: c++, sockets

To learn how to use sockets, I've been working on a simple command-line chat program in OS X.

My goal of the program is to have it work so when one client sends a message, the server relays the message back to all of the clients.

However, when testing this, the server will send messages from the newer clients to the older ones, but will not send messages from the older to the newer.

Here's the loop I'm using:

```
while (1) {

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clientLength);
    if (newsockfd < 0) error("Error accepting");

    connectedClients++;

    std::cout << "Client connected\n"; 

    pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
        // parent; do nothing
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        close(sockfd);
        while(1) {
          // read data 

          // send data
          for (int i=minClient; i<=connectedClients;i++)
              int n = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer)); 
        }
    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

I figure my problem is due to the fact that the parent will still be in an infinite loop and in turn not be aware of new clients.

Comment: It's defined globally as a const

Comment: unrelated: a process or thread per connection will not scale. Consider using an event driven networking library like [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html)

Comment: @Sam, good catch. Actually, it is not unrelated at all. The OP's problem is that he is forking a new process per connection and not managing the shared data correctly.

Comment: By your own admission you are learning about sockets not writing a high performance server so forget about select() or boost asio for now.  Forking children to handle a connection is a perfectly good beginning exercise.

Comment: @Duck -- I agree with you, but for the nature of the server he is writing. If he had written an HTTP server (or FTP, or gopher, or almost anything) instead of an IM server, then fork()ing each server instance makes sense. But he chose IM, which requires interaction between the server instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `fork` a process, you get a whole new copy if its data. Specifically, each server process has its own copy of `connectedClients`, which has the value of the parent process at the moment of the `fork`. If the server parent process later updates `connectedClients`, the then-existing server child processes will never know.

Try printing the value of `connectedClients` from your child server processes to see what I mean.

A good solution is to use `select` or `boost.asio` and don't fork the server process.

Comment: Ah, okay. I noticed that but didn't understand the reason why. I'm guessing I should use something other than fork to do this? EDIT: didn't see your suggestion. Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: "something other than fork" -- yes. Forking a new copy of the server process for every incoming connection is probably not the right architecture. For some client-server projects you can get away with it, but in this case, where the server instances need to share data, you can't. You could try the Boost.Asio link that @Sam Miller  provided. Personally, I think trivial programs are easier with select() or poll().

Comment: I felt that this was simple enough for me to just look up the documentation for select() and give it a shot; it worked, so thanks for all your help!